# Java JOptionPane not working

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, keyevent

I am having a trouble with `JOptionPane`.

```
public void numbericValidater(String number) {
    try {
        double inputNumber = Double.parseDouble(number);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

      //error comes here
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number format");
    }
}
}
```

Now when I press the enter button I want to close it, but what happens is, it is coming again. When I click it by mouse it gets closed.
I am calling above method in `KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)`.
Can anyone explain this?

Comment: hey why do you want to call that method in KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Nidish because it was a key numeric validation dude

Comment: can you post the entire code..............\

Answer (score 0):

But for me when press the enter key it is closing down.

Anyway try this

**For Information message**

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MyMessage" ,"MyTitle", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

**For Error message**

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MyMessage" ,"MyTitle", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

**For Warning message**

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MyMessage" ,"MyTitle", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane makes an additional task run, so you have to add exit code at the end of your class, or whenever you want the message task to end. So in your code after:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number format");
//You have to add the following
System.exit(0);
```